Project owner creating 2 manager users with admin panels for their organization to manage employees
**I am creating a Visitor management system for multiple organizations, i(the owner) am the admin and creating managerial access for each organization, so they can create the employees and give permissions, if the user with managerial access is logged in he shold able to get a blank admin pannel(data) with table present, with models like account , user, n group to manage by its own, for his organization **
from django.db import models
from organisation import GENDER_CHOICES, MARIATAL_STATUS_CHOICES, PERMISSION_CHOICES
from accounts.models import UserAccount
from config.abstract import (
    AbstractCreater,
    AbstractUpdater,
    AbstractActiveStatus,
    AbstractUUID,
    AbstractProfile,
)


class Organisation(
    AbstractCreater, AbstractUpdater, AbstractActiveStatus, AbstractUUID
):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    org_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, help_text="Type of organisation e.g: Technical company"
    )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    org_address = models.TextField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "1. Organisation"
        unique_together = ['name', 'org_type'] 
        ordering = ['-created_at']  

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Unit(
    AbstractCreater, AbstractUpdater, AbstractActiveStatus, AbstractUUID
):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    # F.K's
    org = models.ForeignKey(
        Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="unit_org"
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "2. Unit"
        unique_together = ["name", "org"]
        ordering = ['-created_at'] 


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
    

class Gate(
    AbstractCreater, AbstractUpdater, AbstractActiveStatus
):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    # F.K's
    unit = models.ForeignKey(
        Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="gate_unit"
    )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "3. Gate"
        unique_together = ["name", "unit"]
        ordering = ['id'] 

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
        

class Department(AbstractCreater, AbstractUpdater, AbstractActiveStatus, AbstractUUID):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    department_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, help_text="Type of department e.g: Technical Department"
    )

    # F.K's
    org = models.ForeignKey(
        Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dept_org"
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "4. Department"
        unique_together = ["name", "org"]
        ordering = ['-created_at'] 


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class EmployeeProfile(AbstractCreater, AbstractUpdater, AbstractUUID, AbstractProfile):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=MARIATAL_STATUS_CHOICES)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to="emp_photo", blank=True, null=True)

    # F.K's
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dept_emp"
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "5. Employee Profile"
        unique_together = ["email", "mobile_number"]
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        if self.middle_name:
            return f"{self.first_name} {self.middle_name} {self.last_name}"
        else:
            return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name


class EmployeeAuthorization(AbstractCreater, AbstractUpdater):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        EmployeeProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="permissions"
    )
    user_acc = models.ForeignKey(
        UserAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_acc_emp"
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "6. Employee Authorization"
        unique_together = ["employee", "user_acc"]

